# Kafka producer slow first execution/message

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api

I am having a java web application with a scheduled background job which send kafka message.
I am using the default producer configuration and the job is very simple.
I am not assigning a producer id so each execution a new kafkaproducer is created with a new dynamic id.
When testing i noticed that always the first execution of my job (after my application is up) the job take around 2s but fewer ms in next executions.
I am not having any application cache and creating new instance of kafkaproducer each execution.

Any explanation to this please?is there any static cache in the kafka producer API?( i am always sending to the same topic and not specifying the partition in my producer record)

Comment: 2 days? Please show your code as a [mcve]. Kafka producers use a buffer before sending data; are you not flushing it when the code runs?

Comment: Sorry- spelling mistake.I mean 2s.I will share code when I will connect but I can confirm it is very basic code with default producer configuration.I am not flushing my producer, just send and than close

Comment: Does the topic you're producing to already exist? If not, and you allow for auto topic creation, then the broker needs to take time to actually create the topic